# Comprehensive documentation on creating embedded app template for CRM Analytics

Tags: tableau-crm, crm-analytics

We are trying to build a salesforce crm analytics "embeddedapp" template type which can be auto installed in any subscribers org and added to a lightning record or home page. Where we are struggling is to be able to find a comprehensive developer document or any training material/trail head which can help us create one from scratch.
Most of the documents we got just talks about the embedded app but we need a guide on building one from scratch.

Please note that we are able to create "app" template and use them in analytics studio but we cannot distribute that to any subscriber who doesn't have analytics studio.